# Insert Joomla Html code in Jquery

Tags: jquery, joomla

I'm wondering if it is possible to insert something like the following with jquery

```
$("#main_header").replaceWith("<div class='header_small'><div class='citation'>

//and here should come for example a module position <jdoc:include type="modules" name="right"  style="css-teske" headerLevel="3" />

</div></div>");
```

thanks for every suggestion

Comment: jQuery is loaded client-side; Joomla tags are parsed server-side. So, no, you can't use jQuery to change Joomla tags. However, you CAN use jQuery to set the container div to `display:none` or something like that.

Comment: Yep you are right. Thanks. To tired to think about on simple things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is loaded client-side; Joomla tags are parsed server-side. So, no, you can't use jQuery to change Joomla tags.

However, you CAN use jQuery to set the container div to `display:none` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need asynchronously loading modules, you should maybe try to develop a component, which would be called over ajax and return the module.
You could use methods like `JModuleHelper::renderModule` or `JModuleHelper::getModule()`.
But if you do not need that, much cleaner solution is hiding the module with Javascript.